# Vertically align the Bootstrap Modal using CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to vertically align the Bootstrap Modal using CSS (or other solution that might be even more elegant than that).

I already tried

```
.modal-dialog {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but no luck. The modal displays to the left top.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use next code:

```
.modal-dialog {
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0; 
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) !important; 
    /* ^ dont forget to prefixize this ^ */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: @Laura just add additional rule: `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) !important;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modal-dialog {
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0; 
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) !important; 
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) !important;  
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) !important;  
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) !important;  
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Above will all prefixes

Comment: trying using without comments